# Data model for fields that change frequently in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the best way to deal with fields that change frequently inside a document for ElasticSearch? Per their [docs about partial updates](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html)...

> Internally, however, the update API simply manages the same retrieve-change-reindex process that we have already described.

In particular, what should be done when the indexing of the document will likely be expensive given the number of indexed field and the size of some of the text fields that have to be analyzed?

As a concrete example, use SO's view and vote counts on questions and answers. It would seem expensive to reindex the text body just to update those values.

Comment: You can enter new votes in new document, and later aggregate to get vote counts ??

Comment: @progrrammer I think you're going to have to give a more detailed answer for me. For example, how would I *join* this new document to the existing document at query time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you shouldn't update so frequently. Perhaps things like vote/views should only be periodically updated in ES, while more critical fields like answers/questions be pushed immediately. Consider what's most important and see if you can get away with some level of staleness.

ElasticSearch is great for text search, but I would not consider ES to support SO in its entirety (or similar applications). It could be a useful tool for searching for answers/questions on SO, or for internal applications (like log/event analysis). But perhaps the actual serving of data could be better done with a different solution? Maybe it should be powered by Cassandra instead for the bulk of the work? You get the idea...

If you want to use ES as a solution to your needs, and you MUST update frequently, you could definitely consider the parent/child model mentioned already. of course, that method will require more memory/disk space, and it will take up more cpu/time when you query for totals. An alternative would be to have the parent store searchable fields, and let the child hold the metadata (where the child's fields are not analyzed). this will allow you to make frequent updates without having to undergo an expensive re-index, since there is nothing to index.

You could also consider what I mentioned above and see if you can get away with some staleness. This can be done in many ways too. You can throttle your requests by type of change, or change the refresh/flush interval, or consider de-duping updates if you are sending updates in bulk. These too have their shortcomings...

Answer (score 1):

I think best way to handle the change is to split the document (you can use Parent child relationship, or just have parent id), and make document as small as possible (moving changeable part to new types) .

This can be a way to accomplish your requirement say SO,

You can use multiple types for this, consider This post (Views and Vote count).

1. Create a type for post, view and vote.
2. For a post , index a document to **post type** (index post id, title description tag), and for every view of that post you can index a document to **view type** (with id of post), and if voted you can index vote with (no of votes , id of post and other info you need [like positive or negative flag] ) to **vote type**.
3. So, to get views for post, use filter of post id, and get document counts in views type
4. To get no of votes, use **stat aggregation** for no of votes , or **terms aggregation** followed by **stat aggregation** for getting positive and negative votes.

This is way I think is best, and there can be other opinion too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I do is that I use a database like mongo or mysql for storing properties that get updated frequently and use elastic search to store documents for text searching.

Example: I want to keep data about a book and its contents and I also want to keep the total number of views, *updating and reindexing the document each time a user views it is a total overkill.*